# Removing specific tag but keeping its child element as it is

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to copy the HTML content of specific tag and and then removing the specific HTML tag and attaching the copied element of that tag to the sibling of removed tag. Is there way to fix solve this issue?

For e.g HTML is like this :

```html
<p>This is sample <span id ="1">text <strong>to v<span>erify</span></strong> the</span> issue</p>
```

I am expecting output like this :

```html
<p>This is sample text <strong>to v<span>erify</span></strong> the issue</p>
```

Now if you observe the span element with id="1" has been removed , but its parent contents are still there which are appended to the siblings of deleted span(id=1) element.

Comment: you forgot the code samples

Comment: @FedeSc added the comment

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I have too low of a rep to be able to comment.

Just as a reminder you can name an elements HTML5 id starting with a digit. But if you do, you can only target that element using the id from javascript not using CSS.

It's hard to tell the problem because I can't see the sample code. Like @FedeSc pointed out you probably forgot to put it in.

Please edit the question with the sample code and I'll gladly see if I can help you.